# Quais as desvantagens de se usar Redis?

Tags: banco-de-dados, cache, redis

Há muitas vantagens em se usar Redis como base de dados, porém isso já temos conhecimento.

Gostaria de saber quais as desvantagens de usar redis ou em quais cenários seria muito "contramão" usá-lo.

Comment: Você usa o Redis como base de dados?

Comment: Trabalho com outra base, que é relacional apenas.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez suas desvantagens se baseiem em conceitos mais avançados da tecnologia, porém, tentarei expor minha visão sobre o mesmo.
 
Um ponto que gosto de deixar claro sobre Redis, é que, ele se tratando de um banco que também persiste em disco, porém sua principal feature seria a alocação direta em memória RAM, com isso, é de suma importância que, seu uso seja bem pensado, pois essa flexibilidade pode resultar em grandes problemas para sua aplicação.
Acredito que desvantagens em sua utilização são realmente limitadas, talvez sua má utilização resulte em novos pontos ou até em comparações com tecnologias similares, porém hoje, não vejo desvantagens em sua utilização, de forma correta e bem pensada, é claro.